# Empty Space between textViews after using of maxWidth

Tags: android, xml

My problem is that maxWidth of the textView, works not as I supposed...

http://joxi.ru/L21LROOCDovlmX

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:text="dwadwada adwdwaddwada"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    />
```

When the text is long then 150dp, he just makes layout_width 150dp, and I have such long space between textViews.

How to fix it? Help me please.

What I need:

http://joxi.ru/brRDYooC8bkg21

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/statistic_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/statistic_margin"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:text="dwadwada adwdwaddwada"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="dwdwadwa"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ll_setTemplate_header_top_margin"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ll_setTemplate_header_top_margin"      />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="dwdwadwa"
    android:textSize="16sp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:maxWidth="150dp"` use fill_parent (android:layout_width)

Comment: No I can't. In this case text can fill the whole line, because it can be more than 300 symbols....

Comment: you can use `android:ellipsize`

Comment: okay .Remove `android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ll_setTemplate_header_top_margin"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ll_setTemplate_header_top_margin"` and see what happen

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code i used here

android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/statistic_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/statistic_margin"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="dwadwada adwdwaddwada"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="dwdwadwa" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/specTextView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="dwdwadwa"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, yeah) Thanks) But I don't want gravity center...(

Comment: Try again i edited code. Set    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
to second and third TextViews

Comment: But what if the length of the text will be short?  http://joxi.ru/Dr8KN77TDbEMA6  Empty spaces... User can write every text, that he wants.

Comment: You can set gravity of first TextView left

If text of first TextView will be short there will be sapce after it.

But if text of secon adn third one will short there are will not be space 
There will be sapce only betwean first and second

Comment: Yes, I understand... But user writes the text into every block. That's a problem... I begin of thinking about the changing of the width dinamically in adapter.